# Does a bijection $\phi$ which is not a morphism between two projective plane curves $C$ and $D$ induces an isomorphism $\phi^{*}$ on function fields?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, curves, elliptic-integrals

I was doing a problem, where I found that $\psi: \mathbb{P}^1 \to Z(x^2z-y^3)$ such that $\psi:(t:s)\to (t^3:t^2s:s^3)$ is a morphism  between $\mathbb{P}^1$ and $C:=Z(x^2z-y^3)$ and $im(\psi)=C$. I also proved that $\phi:C\to \mathbb{P}^1$ such that $(t^3:t^2s:s^3)\to (t:s)$ is not a morphism.

I need to understand whether $\phi$ induces an isomorphism $\phi^{*}$ on function fields and I got completely stuck. I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Aren't any two projective plane curves (on the same projective plane) usually bijectable? Especially over algebraically closed fields.

Answer (score 0):

$\psi : [t:1]\to [t^3:t^2:1]$ is a rational map $\Bbb{P}^1\to Z(x^2z-y^3)\subset \Bbb{P}^2$. What is its inverse ?

Comment: its inverse is $\phi: Z(x^2-y^3)\to \mathbb{P}^1$ such that $(t^3:t^2:1)\to (t:1)$ which is clearly not a morphism, but it is a bijection.

Comment: Not quite, its inverse is a rational map, $[x:y:1]\to  ...$. Then it is easy to compose the rational maps with the rational functions.

Comment: I see! Thank you a lot!